# I have a company registired by my name ,can i have an enterprise developer account

Tags: registration, huawei-mobile-services, account

I have a company registered by my name, can i have an enterprise developer account?
It is allowed to register two accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two account with same details.

However, you can delete the current individual account and register a new account with the original email address or phone number, or use a new email address or mobile number to register another account and get the account verified as an enterprise account.

Please follow the below link for more information:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/help/accountmanagementfaqs-0000001053452580#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001053452580__section498725431119

Note:

1-Deleting an account cannot be undone, and all related data will be permanently deleted.

2-Before deleting an account, you have to either transfer all the apps to another account or you have to delete the apps from your account

3-Without deleting individual account, you cannot create enterprise account with the same mail id or phone number

If you want to transfer your apps from individual account to enterprise account, please follow the below link:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-transferapp-0000001099998802

Please follow the below link for deleting the account:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/account-management-0000001052865467#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001052865467__section79321232492